# after converting python file to one file exe when i run it [FileNotFoundError]

Tags: python, pyinstaller

How to access the file:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

def main():
    with open("pass.txt", "r") as pf:  ## This is line 51 in the screenshot
        passwds = pf.read().splitlines()
    
    # some codes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()  ## This is line 83 in the screenshot
```

I used this

```
pyinstaller --clean --onefile start.py
```

[Screenshot: Note that the files are located next to the executable file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW4tz.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 83, in <module>
  File "start.py", line 51, in main
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pass.txt'
[50416] Failed to execute script 'start' due to unhandled exception!
```

When i used:

```
pyinstaller start.py
```

That is, it is not in one file, it was working without problems, but there are many files next to it, and I do not want this

But when I use make it to one file --onefile the problem occurs

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: We need to see the line(s) of code that is/are causing the error — i.e. how is `pass.txt` be accessed?

Comment: I added it to the question, check again

Comment: The problem has to do with your use of `__file__` to change the directory. See pyinstaller's documentation on [Using \_\_file__](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file).

Comment: I used it and the result is like this `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Mr.Neo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI320802\\pass.txt'`

Comment: It's `sys._MEIPASS`.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741) but the result is the same:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Mr.Neo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI237802\\pass.txt'`

Comment: Try `os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)`. Another possibility is `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`. If those don't work, I have no further ideas.

Comment: I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/404750/18248481)
thanks for your efforts I really appreciate you martineau <3

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/404750/18248481)

thanks for your efforts
I really appreciate you [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) <3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).