# How to get the path to the directory where the .exe file is located after Pyinstaller compiles python script

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have an app that accesses .txt files that contains user data from a subdirectory where the .py file is located. After Pyinstaller is used to compile the .py file to a .exe file the path changed to `AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI185962\<subdirectory>\<user data.txt>` when I print the path. My question is how do I come up with the path to where the `.exe` file is all the time, because I want to make my program be distributeable so I don't want to use a hardcoded path or if I move the folder around.

So for example if I have my program.exe in the directory `C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/project` then how do I access te subdirectory `C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/project/data`. I tried importing os.path and had

`path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))`

to get the path, but it is still pointing to the `C:\User\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI185962\<subdirectory>\<user data.txt>`.

I am new to compiling so I don't know much about pyinstaller at all. I also can't seem to find any thing on this issue either.

Comment: [`sys.executable`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0)

Comment: One popular convention is to use the users ~home directory and either create or look for a directory that matches the name of your program preceded by a period `~/.AppName/userfiles.txt`  then there is no need to move the directory around if the executable ever get's relocated or if there is an updated version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining application path in a Python EXE generated by pyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404744/determining-application-path-in-a-python-exe-generated-by-pyinstaller)