# EXE created with PyInstaller: "Cannot copy tree 'Y': not a directory"

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller, distutils, file-structure

I converted a file, `main.py`, into `main.exe`, using PyInstaller. `main.py` doesn't throw any error, but `main.exe` does.

The script didn't execute fully, so I used a `try-catch` and got this:

> Cannot copy tree 'Y': not a directory

It looks like it's a problem with how I converted it into an EXE with PyInstaller.

This is the PyInstaller command I used to convert it into an EXE:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon "X/logo.ico"
--name "H" --add-data "X/Y;Y/" --add-data 
"X/dmode.png;." --add-data "X/lu.png;." --add-data "X/toggle.png;." 
--add-data "X/white.png;." --paths "C:/Users/Username/venv/Lib/site-packages" 
--hidden-import "tkinter" --hidden-import "os" --hidden-import "sys" 
--hidden-import "distutils" --hidden-import "shutil" 
--hidden-import "win32gui"  "X/main.py"
```

And this is the file structure:

*`X`*

- build, dist and other folders created by PyInstaller and PyCharm (IDE)
- *`Y`*

  - *`JS`*

    - cS.js
  - i.jpeg
  - M.json
- *`Z`* (the directory in which `Y` will be copied)
- dmode.png
- logo.ico
- lu.png
- main.py
- toggle.png
- white.png

`X` is the directory in which `main.py` is. This is apparently the code which causes the error:

```py
from os.path import join
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

if not os.path.exists(join(application_path, "Z")):
    copy_tree("Y", join(application_path, "Z"))
```

But I don't get any errors when I run the PyInstaller command in CMD. So, where have I gone wrong? Have I used `--add-data` incorrectly? Is `application_path` wrong (copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/404750/16136190))? If yes, please mention where I've used it incorrectly and where I have referenced the files/directories incorrectly. I prefer changing the command instead of the `.spec` file, so a PyInstaller (CMD) command would be helpful.

Comment: please post the error message you are receiving.

Comment: @Alexander, "Cannot copy tree 'Y': not a directory" is all I get. I've tried many other ways, like changing all the destinations to `.` and then rewriting the file references, but I get `PermissionError`s ('Permission Denied'; though I used `--uac-admin` and have given permissions via File Explorer, even when I run it as administrator), or it just doesn't copy. It simply doesn't copy the files (the code to copy runs). I'll edit my question to include what else I've tried.